# Apple needs additional time to evaluate submission and Apple Developer Program account

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

We are a small Startup and we tried to publish our app a few days ago on the AppStore. In our app, the user selects an image it is processed in the cloud. The process is AI-based and takes a long time, about 15 minutes. The user is requested to leave the app and a push notification is sent when the process is finished. The app was rejected because of this waiting period and we were requested to keep the processing time smaller than 5 minutes as mentioned in the guidelines (BTW/ we never found this mentioned in the guidelines).

We did our best to reduce the time but the App was rejected 3 times for the same reason. On the fourth try, we received this Email

> We need additional time to evaluate your submission and Apple
> Developer Program account. Your submission status will appear as
> "Rejected" in App Store Connect while we investigate. However, we do
> not require a revised binary or additional information from you at
> this time.

We did some research and we were shocked to see that many people did not receive any information weeks, and often months, after having received this message.

Has anyone experienced this?

We managed to reduce the time to one minute. We also fixed a few other bugs in the app and we think that we are now completely conforming to the guideline.

Do you think it makes sense to submit the same app with another account or will this result in more problems with Apple?

Comment: Did you ever get your app approved? I just got this error for the first time. I have about 10 apps on the App Store, I hope the doesn't effect my whole portfolio